# Returning text from backgroundworker

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to display results from my backgroundworker into a textbox. I looked online, and it seems like I am using the right code, but its nothing doing anything.

**Code:**

```
 Do While sr.Peek <> -1
            line = sr.ReadLine()
            BackgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(30, "Searching Log: Started")
            If line.TrimStart(trimchars).StartsWith(TDate.Text) And line.Trim(trimchars).Contains("[Log Number:") Then
                ' found pattern 
                BackgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(40, "Searching Log: Complete")
                'SN.Text = line
                e.Result = line
                NoteLab.Visible = False

            ElseIf line.TrimStart(trimchars).StartsWith(Ydate.Text) And line.Trim(trimchars).Contains("[Log Number:") Then
                BackgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(50, "Searching Log: Failed - Searching for yesterdays")
                'SN.Text = line
                e.Result = line
                NoteLab.Visible = True
                BackgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(60, "Searching Log: Complete")
                '
            End If

Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.RunWorkerCompleted
        SN.Text = e.Result
    End Sub
```

**Error:**
There is NO error. It just does NOT put anything into the textbox.

I think that should be all information needed. Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: What is `NoteLab`? From the way you are using it, it appears to be a control.  What is the PRIMARY rule of using a `BackgroundWorker`?  DO NOT touch the UI in the `DoWork` event handler.  If you want to update the UI then do so ONLY in the `ProgressChanged` or `RunWorkerCompleted` event handlers.

Comment: @jmcilhinney notelab is something I just forgot to comment out when I copied the code from a OnClick event to a BackGroundWorker. I knew that part would not work, just spaced it out.

Comment: And for the record, I did NOT blind copy anything. I read some information from MSDN, and deceided to change the code to a backgroundworker as it seemed cleaner, excuse me for trying to learn @varocarbas

Comment: Please edit your question and show us the entire `DoWork` event handler, the entire `ProgressChanged` event handler and the entire `RunWorkerCompleted` event handler, all as they are right now, ensuring that you have tested your code again if you have made any changes since originally posting.  Also, have you debugged your code, because that should always be done before posting a question here?  You say that there's no error but have you tested the `e.Error` property in the `RunWorkerCompleted` event handler?

Comment: Try placing Console.writeline(line) inside each if..elseif and see what values are there.